# How to execute a command from with in MSI?

Tags: command-line, windows-installer

I have a installation setup with works like this: /exec.exe /some-command

This whole setup is located on a shared disk to which my target machine have access to. All i want is to create a small MSI wrapper that basically executes the above command. I don't need to any other fancy things?

I looked up on the web; there are tools that create MSI for you but they generate huge amount of other things with them as well.

My need is very simple and straight forward. It would be great if some could help me with this issue.

Thanks,
Omer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [WiX](http://wix.sourceforge.net/) it is very simple to create a MSI-Wrapper that just executes a custom action firing up a command line.

Comment: any pointers?  I also would like to be able to do this.  I;m trying to explore wix3.5 but not sure where to start

Answer (score 2):

MSI seems like the wrong tool for the job in this instance. A big reason that MSI's are popular, is because they allow for easy install/uninstall in one package (among *many* other things).

I'd suggest using a simple batch (or vbscript, or perl script, or whatever) wrapped up in a self-extracting executable. This way you can include custom logic, all without the overhead of the MSI. Besides, you aren't using any of the functionality of an MSI --- except that it wraps up files into a single file.

You can use a pay program such as WinZip Self-Extractor, or you can use 7-zip (free) and a GUI app someone has written to create self-extracting EXE's: [7-ZIP SFX MAKER](http://teejee2008.wordpress.com/7-zip-sfx-maker/)

I've used 7-zip sfx maker before, and I can vouch that it works very well.

Comment: MSI is just correct to use the WindowsInstaller DB for managing the installed/uninstalled apps on one pc, as well as to manage the installation like wanted. Though MSI is not nearly ment for just calling an external installer, it is well able to do so.

Comment: It is *able* to do so. Just like you can use a hammer to put screws into a wall...but why would you? MSI provides nearly zero benefit here, and no advantages (in this instance) over SFX installation.