# Run a batch file during WIX installation

Tags: wix

I have tried various "solutions" to this problem to no avail. Right now my setup is like this:

```
    <Fragment>
    <CustomAction Id="BatchCmd" ExeCommand="[INSTALLFOLDER]registerDLL.bat"
Directory="INSTALLFOLDER" Execute="deferred" Return="asyncWait"
     />
    <InstallExecuteSequence>
        <Custom Action="BatchCmd" After="InstallFiles">NOT Installed</Custom>
        
    </InstallExecuteSequence>
</Fragment>
```

The registerDLL file is part of a WIX component that is defined somewhere else in the file. It is correctly copied to the INSTALLFOLDER directory.

The batch file is not executed at all. And I don't really know how to debug this. I mean gosh, it could not have been any more complex to run a simple batch file.

What is the *simplest* approach to run a batch file inside WIX?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly a solution per se, though it *is* the solution to my specific problem.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1165130/5088769